# The ""sort"" value has to be formed as this example: ""field_ASC""

Tags: vb.net, prestashop

I'm developing an integration between a ERP and a Prestashop store, I'm now trying to use a product filter to check if a product already exists, so i can either add a new product or update an existing one.

When I try to get the filter result i got a XML response with the following error message

```
<![CDATA[The ""sort"" value has to be formed as this example: ""field_ASC"" or '[field_1_DESC,field_2_ASC,field_3_ASC,...]' (""field"" has to be an available field)]]>
```

I didn't understand what that really means, I have searched around a while and coudn't find any specific problem like this and all the examples I've found are the same.

Here is my code, it is in VB and I'm using Bukimedia Prestasharp

```
Dim oProdFac = New ProductFactory(oParameters.UrlAPI, oParameters.TokenAPI, oParameters.KeyAPI)
    Dim objFiltro = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim listFilterProducts As New List(Of Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.product)

    objFiltro.Add("reference", "My_Product_Id")
    listFilterProducts = oProdFac.GetByFilter(objFiltro, "null", "null")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Allright, the answer is SO SIMPLE that i felt ashamed.

I was sending incorrect parameters in the GetByFilter function.
I've changed this

```
 listFilterProducts = oProdFac.GetByFilter(objFiltro, "null", "null")
```

to this

```
 listFilterProducts = oProdFac.GetByFilter(objFiltro, "reference_ASC", "null")
```

Just like the xml message said. It solved the problem.